# matlab/octave: exponential scale on x axis in plot

Tags: matlab, plot, scale, octave

In **Matlab** or **Octave** I want to plot a vector with an **exponential scale on the x axis**.

Changing the `xticks` and `xticklabel` do not seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try using [semilogx](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/semilogx.html).